# Java package does not exist after library import

Tags: java, package, importerror

I added a jar library to the project that contains the package, but it doesn't recognize that. Why do I get the error? And how do I fix it?

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot_1]

<sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a mongo driver. It's javadocs. Just use this Mongo Driver(Direct Link) http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.0.4/mongo-java-driver-3.0.4.jar

*P.S. Small advice: Use Maven or Gradle is the better way. And you may use this repository for downloading JARs: http://mvnrepository.com/*

Comment: Extremely helpful for a Java newbie. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need add jar to classpath (not doc's in your situation)

I know 5 ways to do it:

1. Include the JAR name in CLASSPATH environment variable
2. Include name of JAR file in -classpath command line option
3. Include the jar name in the Class-Path option in the manifest
4. Use Java 6  wildcard option to include multiple JAR
5. Adding JAR in ext directory e.g. C:\Program
   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre\lib\ext

But I recommend you to use Maven or Gradle

If you could use Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

If you could use Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.0.4'
}
```